# GetLastInputInfo is user specific - is there something similar which gives machine-wide last input time

Tags: c#, .net, input, idle-processing

As per MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302%28VS.85%29.aspx

> GetLastInputInfo does not provide
>   system-wide user input information
>   across all running sessions. Rather,
>   GetLastInputInfo provides
>   session-specific user input
>   information for only the session that
>   invoked the function.

Is there something similar which provides a system-wide last user input information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is through hooking into the shell.

This is (obviously) something that must be done carefully and is something not feasible in managed code until this is fully supported by the operating system (not till windows 7) so you  will have to use some unmanaged code to achieve this, perhaps updating some global state queryable from your managed code. The API for this is [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx).

With the session isolation of Vista onwards you will need elevated priviledges to do this for other sessions. In this taking cues from how keyloggers work may help but I do not have a ready link to some source for this.

As a first start here is the source from the windows port of [condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/) for spotting keyboard activity:

```
/***************************************************************
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1990-2007, Condor Team, Computer Sciences Department,
 * University of Wisconsin-Madison, WI.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you
 * may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  You may
 * obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 ***************************************************************/


#include <windows.h>

// Shared DATA
// put in here data that is needed globally
#pragma data_seg(".SHARDATA")
HHOOK hHook = NULL;
LONG KBkeyhitflag = 0;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.SHARDATA,RWS")

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KBHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam)
{
    InterlockedExchange(&KBkeyhitflag,1);

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
}

HINSTANCE g_hinstDLL = NULL;

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif //__cplusplus


int __declspec( dllexport) WINAPI KBInitialize(void)
{
    hHook=(HHOOK)SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD,(HOOKPROC)KBHook,g_hinstDLL,0);
    return hHook ? 1 : 0;
}

int __declspec( dllexport) WINAPI KBShutdown(void)
{
    if ( UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook) )
        return 1;   // success
    else
        return 0;   // failure
}

int __declspec( dllexport)  WINAPI KBQuery(void)
{
    if ( InterlockedExchange(&KBkeyhitflag,0) )
        return 1;   // a key has been hit since last query
    else
        return 0;   // no keys hit since asked last
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
} // extern "C"
#endif //defined(__cplusplus)

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hInstDLL, ULONG fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            g_hinstDLL = (HINSTANCE)hInstDLL;
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(g_hinstDLL);
            break;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some work recently. Multiple users can use `WTSServer` to obtain their [`WTSInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wtsinfoa) It includes a lot of information about users, and I hope it can help you.

```cpp
typedef struct _WTSINFOA {
  WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
  DWORD                  SessionId;
  DWORD                  IncomingBytes;
  DWORD                  OutgoingBytes;
  DWORD                  IncomingFrames;
  DWORD                  OutgoingFrames;
  DWORD                  IncomingCompressedBytes;
  DWORD                  OutgoingCompressedBy;
  CHAR                   WinStationName[WINSTATIONNAME_LENGTH];
  CHAR                   Domain[DOMAIN_LENGTH];
  CHAR                   UserName[USERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
  LARGE_INTEGER          ConnectTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER          DisconnectTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER          LastInputTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER          LogonTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER          CurrentTime;
} WTSINFOA, *PWTSINFOA;
```